# Confirmed Transaction

Tags: transactions, confirmations

If a transaction gets a minimum of 3 confirmations, does that mean that the BTCs have reached the destination address? I have a case where the transaction has gone through multiple confirmations but the order status on the payee platform is still showing "unpaid".

Comment: It might be useful to provide a name of the "payee platform". On another note: How long did it take till your transaction received it's first confirmation?

Comment: It took around 1 hour to get the first confirmation. I am asking this question because the transaction is shown as "Sent" and  "Confirmed" from my Blockchain wallet. Moreover, on the Blockchain chart it shown as "Spent Output". However, the payee did not execute my order. It seems that I have been cheated/scammed. If I well understood your question, the name of the payy platform is Sun Mining.

Answer (score 1):

if your transaction has 3 confirmations this means that your transaction is in the blockchain. well. many platforms have a "minimum amount of confirmations", for example i often see 7 or 10 transactions as requirement for acceptance of this payment. this has justified technical reasons. you should wait some blocks and then your payment will probably also be accepted.

Comment: I am asking this question because the transaction is shown as "Sent" and  "Confirmed" from my Blockchain wallet. Moreover, on the Blockchain chart it shown as "Spent Output". However, the payee did not execute my order. It seems that I have been cheated/scammed.